# How to introduce n distinct symbols in Coq

Tags: coq

I have built a record for group. Now I would like to build a group with n elements (e.g. 10 elements) by specifying the group multiplication table.

My issue is that I would need n symbols to serve as a ground set for my group. I will need Coq to know that these n elements are all distinct.

So far I have figured

```
Inductive ground_set : Type :=  A : ground_set | B : ground_set.
Axiom diff: A<>B.
```

which works for n=2. I don't know how to scale this to many elements without creating some ugly code.

I would guess that there is a better way to generate such a set, but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wild guess, but maybe something like:

```
Inductive ground_set (limit: nat): Set :=
  | Elem : forall n, n < limit -> ground_set limit.

Lemma ground_set_discr (limit:nat): forall n p (hn: n < limit) (hp: p < limit),
  n <> p -> Elem _ n hn <> Elem _ p hp.
Proof.
intros n p hn hp hdiff h.
inversion h; subst; clear h.
now apply hdiff.
Qed.
```

Comment: You might need some proof irrelevance (which is always true on `nat` proposition anyway) to reason with such dependent types.

Comment: A very similar approach would be to use the `Fin.t` type defined in the standard library ([`Coq.Vectors.Fin`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Vectors.Fin.html)): "`fin n` is a convenient way to represent \1 .. n\".

Comment: I agree, using Fin type or mathcomp 'I_n would be the best option, for all the support is already here. I wasn't sure about the question, so I tried the naïve approach ;)

Answer (score 2):

For `Inductive` definitions, you get inequalities between constructors for free:

```
Inductive ground_set : Type :=  A : ground_set | B : ground_set.

Lemma diff: A <> B.
Proof.
  discriminate.
Qed.
```

Comment: Alright, that work for the distinction part. how about generating a ground set of some integer size, much bigger than 2?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the best thing is to use the approach outlined by Vinz. Using some libraries would help, for instance, in mathcomp, which is specialized for reasoning about finite groups, you can create a type with `n` distinct elements just by writing `'I_n`, and you will get for free many properties, such as finiteness.